# Hibernate generates unwanted aliases when using @Formula annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

When I give to the @Formula annotation this piece of code :

```
@Formula("(SELECT SUM(commission.montant) FROM commission, affaire)")
private Double totalCommissionsMCourant;
```

Hibernates executes this SQL request :

```
[...,(SELECT SUM(commission.montant) FROM commission, a1_0.affaire) ...]
```

As you can see, the "FROM commission, affaire" turns into "FROM commission, a1_0.affaire", which makes the SQL request invalid.

**Disclaimer :** I know that having this type of calculated field here does not make sense but this is a simplified version of what I'd want to have.

Do you have any idea on how to prevent this problem from happening ?

Here is part of the Entity's code :

```
@Entity(name = "Apporteur")
@Table(name = "apporteur")
public class ApporteurEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Formula("(SELECT SUM(commission.montant) FROM commission, affaire)")
  private Double totalCommissionsMCourant;

}
```

Hibernate version : 6.0.0

Comment: That `FROM commission, affaire` is meant to be a cross-join, right? Did you try with `commission JOIN affaire` or something like this? You might also want to provide the Hibernate version you're using.

Comment: It is indeed ! But using JOIN still generates an unwanted alias ("FROM commission JOIN a1_0.affaire"). I've added the Hibernate version I'm using

Comment: Can you maybe provide the complete query or, if it is complex, a [mcve]? Is there any column in the query that is called `affaire` which Hibernate might get confused with?

Comment: I would suggest you to rather use a separate query to fetch this data. Do you really want to execute such an expensive subquery for every apporteur row that you fetch? I don't think so. In fact, I'm pretty sure that you only have a single place in your code where you actually need this information, so why not write a query for that place and run the query?